# Rails 4: How to multiply in a view an element based of how many times was selected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have a table which contains some elements and that element can be selected just adding a tick. Every element can have more of one tick or zero ticks. On the side of this table, I have a button called generate. When it is pressed a list of the elements is shown. like:

- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3

What I need is to show the repetition of the same element for how many ticks its has. 
like:
Example Element 1 has 3 ticks, Element 2 has 1 tick, Element 3 has 4 ticks.
The list should look:

- Element 1 (Tick1)
- Element 1 (Tick2)
- Element 1 (Tick3)
- Element 2 (Tick1)
- Element 3 (Tick1)
- Element 3 (Tick2)
- Element 3 (Tick3)
- Element 3 (Tick4)

Also what I need to show on top of every repeated Element a title saying like 1,2,3...

Will be good to see an example through JSFiddle to understand the method for this or some other example in Rails.